# Creating a bilingual domain using multiple html files

Tags: javascript, html, multilingual

I am an extremely beginner level web-designer. Recently I was hired in a company to create a domain from scratch. They requested their domain to be bilingual. I do not know any JavaScript, so I came up with the idea of creating two separate html files in which I translate the content to the required language and then just make a ref link so when the user clicks on the en.icon the English html page pops up.

Is this solution functional, will it cost them more money when hosting their website? does it affect loading times significantly?

If no what are possible solutions I can proceed with.

Comment: Have you looked at, or are you using subdomains ? you can add subdomains for each site and add the language specific files in there e.g. en.example.com, fr.example.com.

Comment: I was thinking i could do it in a way of www.example.com/mainen.html and www.example.com/mainit.html . Can't this solution work?. I will look in the subdomains, but aren't they difficult when using windows? - Thank you for your response

Comment: Ah I was just looking at the subdomain and it is probably what I have in mind as well. I will try to do it like this. I am sorry again I am complete beginner I just began 1 month ago to study code. Thank you

Comment: No problem, that's what this site is for! good luck.

Comment: Another method that you could look into is putting a google translate button on your page and letting google do the work. While the translation isn't perfect it is readable and understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it would be very ineffective for you to write a different html page for each language. If the project is small and won't expand in the future it should do the trick but it definitely isn't the smart way. Imagine having a 1000 page website.

I would suggest that you learnt a bit of Javascript and change the text in the current element depending on what the current language is.
You can store the current language in a cookie or in the localStorage/sessionStorage (the second option is really simple).

It will help you a lot if you look up basic **DOM** (**HTML Tree**) manipulation in Javascript. Do not worry if you don't grasp everything from the beginning. Everyone has went through that. It is simple and it shouldn't take you that much time. Take your time with javascript and it will pay off in a few months.

After you've got the basics using vanilla Javascript you can try ot jQuery. It will simplify things a lot but I recommend learning things the hard way so that you have a deeper understanding of how things work.

Whether or not you want to become a developer or you just want to be a designer, learning the basics of programming will be of much use.

I hope I was helpful. Good luck with the website!

Comment: You are probably correct, I will attempt to study some basic java. Sadly I am only keen c++, but I'm guessing it won't be so different. If you can suggest any books or tutorials I can find on the web, I would be very much obliged. Thank you for your time.